# PostGIS 2.1 ST_EstimatedExtent returns error

Tags: postgis

In absence of statistics (empty table or no ANALYZE called) the function ST_EstimatedExtent(schema,table,geom_column) should return NULL (PostGIS 2.1).

In my case, the function returns

```
FEHLER:  stats for "table1.the_geom" do not exist


********** Fehler **********

FEHLER: stats for "table1.the_geom" do not exist
SQL Status:XX000
```

The table table1 is empty, so the function should return NULL?!
I also run an ANALYZE on the table.

Comment: I can only confirm. My PostGIS version checked with select postgis_version() is "2.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1".

Answer (score 3):

The docs for [ST_EstimatedExtent](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_EstimatedExtent.html) say:

> In absence of statistics (empty table or no ANALYZE called) this function returns NULL. Prior to version 1.5.4 an exception was thrown.

The following sequence of queries would seem to demonstrate that the word "or" above should be replaced with "and", i.e.:

> In absence of statistics (empty table **AND** no ANALYZE called) this function returns NULL. Prior to version 1.5.4 an exception was thrown.

```
SELECT ST_EstimatedExtent('no_table', 'geom');
```

> ERROR:  relation "no_table" does not exist

```
CREATE TABLE  no_table (id serial, geom geometry);
SELECT ST_EstimatedExtent('no_table', 'geom');
```

> ERROR:  stats for "no_table.geom" do not exist

```
ANALYZE no_table;
SELECT ST_EstimatedExtent('no_table', 'geom');
```

> ERROR:  stats for "no_table.geom" do not exist

```
INSERT into no_table (geom) select st_makepoint(0,0);
SELECT ST_EstimatedExtent('no_table', 'geom');
```

> ERROR:  stats for "no_table.geom" do not exist

```
ANALYZE no_table;
SELECT ST_EstimatedExtent
```

> st_estimatedextent
>   
>  -------------------- 
>   BOX(0 0,0 0)

From which it would seem the table has to be non-empty **AND** have analyze called on it. So, the docs should change or to and.

As @user30184 has pointed out, there is [an open issue](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3396) for the error behavior of this function.

Comment: There is an open issue at https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3396